# Where in Islam is it mentioned that Muslims have to prayer 5 times a day?

Tags: salat, islamic-basis

Where in the Quran and Hadith is it mentioned that Muslims have to pray 5 times a day?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does the idea of prayer 5 times a day come from the Qur'an?](http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/928/does-the-idea-of-prayer-5-times-a-day-come-from-the-quran)

Comment: @Medi1Saif The question asks for reference from both Hadith and the Qur'an. It's not an exact duplicate.

Comment: @MohammadSakibArifin I would agree with you and it is a community choice to accept or refuse my duplicate qualification. But IMO once we have a clear ruling in the Quran we don't need a backup from hadith and that's the reason behind my choice at the time. Also the question isn't a real new question and this is what i would qualify a duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

> Where in the Quran and Hadith is it mentioned that Muslims have to pray 5 times a day?

### In Hadith.

A hadith narrated by Abu Dhar specifically mentions that Muslims have to pray five prayers a day. Narrated Abu Dhar:

> ...Ibn Hazm and Anas bin Malik said: The Prophet (ﷺ) said, "Then Allah
> enjoined fifty prayers on my followers when I returned with this order
> of Allah, I passed by Moses who asked me, 'What has Allah enjoined on
> your followers?' I replied, 'He has enjoined fifty prayers on them.'
> Moses said, 'Go back to your Lord (and appeal for reduction) for your
> followers will not be able to bear it.' (So I went back to Allah and
> requested for reduction) and He reduced it to half.
>
> When I passed by Moses again and informed him about it, he said, 'Go back to your Lord as your followers will not be able to bear it.' So I returned to Allah
> and requested for further reduction and half of it was reduced. I
> again passed by Moses and he said to me: 'Return to your Lord, for
> your followers will not be able to bear it. So I returned to Allah and
> He said, **'These are five prayers and they are all (equal to) fifty
> (in reward) for My Word does not change.'**
>
> I returned to Moses and he
> told me to go back once again. I replied, 'Now I feel shy of asking my
> Lord again.' Then Gabriel took me till we '' reached Sidrat-il-Muntaha
> (Lote tree of; the utmost boundary) which was shrouded in colors,
> indescribable. Then I was admitted into Paradise where I found small
> (tents or) walls (made) of pearls and its earth was of musk."

### In the Qur'an.

This part of the question has already been answered in the [answer wiki to "Does the idea of praying 5 times a day come from the Qur'an?"](https://islam.stackexchange.com/a/26389/15772)

Reference: [Sahih al-Bukhari » Book of Prayers (كتاب الصلاة)](http://sunnah.com/bukhari/8)

Answer (score -1):

there is no exact mention in Quran that Muslims should pray 5 times a day, but you can fined that Resoul Allah Muhammed pray 5 times in many story from his companions, and that enough because not everything should mentioned in Quran

Comment: i suggest you to read answer in here http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/928/does-the-idea-of-prayer-5-times-a-day-come-from-the-quran