# Is numerology haram or shirk

Tags: shirk

Why are we obliged to do a thing certain number of times in Islam?

For example. Washing face in wudhoo 3 times. Specific number of rakah in namaz. If doing a wazifa, then reciting a surah a particular number of times.

Is it related to numerology? Do these numbers mean anything? Do they represent something? Can "relative" unseen be found through these numbers? Explain in detail please.

And if I believe that numbers do mean something for example, 222 means you're on a right path, am I a kafir for believing that?

After using subliminals and frequencies, we start seeing these angel numbers more often, and they say that these numbers mean something. They say "angels" guide you through these numbers. Is it true or "shirk" or "haram" to believe it?

**Just like magic is real but is haram, the same way, as numerology is haram, but is it real?**

**Do numbers represent something?**

I watched an Islamic video that was explaining the concept of Illuminati, and the person said that the secret of universe are in the form of numbers, and those evil people know it and use these numbers to their advantage. Is numerology magic? Do numbers represent something? Someone says ilm jafar is allowed. People say angel numbers represent some things for example, 222 means the path you're on, is right. 111 means it's time to make a wish. 666 is the devil number. *You might have understood what I'm trying to say.*

Kingly enlighten in detail. Thank you.

Comment: Salam and welcome to IslamSE the Q&A site about Islam. For further information about our site and model consider taking the [tour] and checking our [help].

Comment: First of all what is the basis of your claim that we are obliged to perform things a certain number of times? And what is the relation between following the sunnah and numerology one thing is part of the religion and faith while the other is in best case a pseudo-science.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Maybe these posts are helpful [Is pseudosciene generally forbidden or discouraged?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/36316/is-pseudoscience-generally-forbidden-or-discouraged) and [The importance of digit 7 in Islam](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/56011/the-importance-of-digit-7-in-islam) ...

Answer (score 0):

I do not think the number in which why the reason it is done three times is specified somewhere but there is this hadith just in case.
"(The slave of 'Uthman) I saw 'Uthman bin 'Affan asking for a tumbler of water (and when it was brought) he poured water over his hands and washed them thrice and then put his right hand in the water container and rinsed his mouth, washed his nose by putting water in it and then blowing it out. then he washed his face and forearrlns up to the elbows thrice, passed his wet hands over his head and washed his feet up to the ankles thrice. Then he said, "Allah's Apostle said 'If anyone Performs ablution like that of mine and offers a two-rak'at prayer during which he does not think of anything else (not related to the present prayer) then his past sins will be forgiven.' "

So, after this hadith, there isn't really a specific reason as to why  it is done three times, but if you do it that way, your sins will be forgiven.

Also, for the second claim numerology and magic are not the same thing. Magic could  harm someone else with "spells" since muslims do believe in magic. It is also shirk (Associating partners with God) because you would be associating partners with material things, like thinking a rock is powerful when it is just a rock. (which muslims do not believe in)
"angel numbers" are haram because it is considered shirk as well , and seeking knowledge fo the unseen which is haram, and can lead to deviation from the true path of Islam (basically also thinking those numbers mean something and u start "worshipping them"
Hope that clears things up