# How to do ghusl of janabat and hayd?

Tags: practical-islam, islamic-philosophy, ghusl, islamic-scholar

As I know you have to do the ghsul in the end of period so I checked online how to do the ghusl of janaba and Hayd together and some said you have to do the two ghusl differently.

If I need to do it differently which one should I do first **or** should I do one ghsul for janaba and hayd and to say thus as the niyyat **I'm making ghsul to be clean from janaba and hayd**

Comment: Please answer me i need to do ghusl right now

Comment: This is simply speaking a question duplicate stop asking the same question again and again. Ask one question per post. If you need a fast answer you should ask a scholar not random people on the web.

Comment: But no one is answering me please help me

Comment: I'm going cry brother I cant understand

Comment: Please answer me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First ghusl must be done to regain tahrah (ritual purity) in order to be able to pray and worship. If a woman became junub during her menses. Even if she performed ghusl for Janabah she doesn't get in a state of tahrah unless by coincidence her menses ended.
So from a logical point of view ghusl (of Janabah) is not necesarry, but in case of a supposed haram (illegal) reason for this Janabah tawbah(repentance) is required. Nevertheless she might perform ghusl for Janabah during her menses. But it won't be a valid reason for being able to pray as her menses has not yet ended and praying during menses is haram (See for example: [Do women need to check their menstruation before Fajr to see if they are required to also pray the previous night Isha?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/56242/do-women-need-to-check-their-menstruation-before-fajr-to-see-if-they-are-require/56244#56244)).
Otherwise if more than one reason for ghusl applies one could perform one ghusl for different purposes.

The matter of niyyah (intention) has been discussed and answered on the site before: it is not necessary nor more than permissible to utter it, as niyyah is in the heart. Further some scholars like the Hanafi school of fiqh and imam Sufyan a-Thawry say niyyah is neither required for ghusl nor wudu' nor any non pure worship. (See my answer on: [Is niyyat for ghsul needed?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/61916/is-niyyat-for-ghsul-needed))

As for how to perform ghusl this has also been answered on the site.

The same applies to the topic of menses and how to identify its ending. (See [I have an period where the blood comes in small amounts; is it valid for me to fast or pray?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/40872/i-have-an-period-where-the-blood-comes-in-small-amounts-is-it-valid-for-me-to-f))

Comment: I still kinda dont get please answer me in simple way. Do you mean that I need to do one ghusl after my period and intention of janabat and hayd and then that's it?

Comment: I mean that you need to do one ghusl at the end of your period with the intention of hayd. While it is recommended to do one now with the intention of Janabah.

Comment: So should I now to my bathroom and do ghusl for janaba while I'm on period 2nd day

Comment: And then do ghusl for hayd in the end of the of my period?

Comment: Brother reply to me please

Comment: ??? Sir please answer me soon as possible 

Comment: You are able to read. You are asking the same stuff again and again. The answer is clearly stated in both my answer and the answer you have found on the net. There's no contradiction between both in any way. There is nothing to add except with the recommendation to seek professional help for your OCD. So please don't ask me again about these things, don't waste other people's time and search for professional help.

Answer (score 0):

**this person is the same person who asked the question and I've checked a [website](https://www.sistani.org/english/qa/01198/) and it says this**

> **Question**: A woman was in the state of Janabat and she realized that her monthly period had started. Can she perform one Ghusl later with the intention of both Ghusl-e Hayz and Ghusl-e Janabat?

**Answer**: Yes, one Ghusl is sufficient. It is permissible to perform one Ghusl with the intention of many obligatory Ghusl's such as Ghusl Haydh, Ghusl Janaba, Ghusl Nifas and Ghusl for touching a dead body. She can also perform the Ghusl Janaba whilst in the state of her monthly period, and then after its completion, she will need to perform the Ghusl of Haydh.

(So does the answer mean that I can perform ghusl of janabat while on period and I can perform ghusl of hayd when I finish my period)
*shia*

Comment: Be aware that the source of your quote is a shi'a website. In case you are looking for a specific view you should make it clear in your post!